# The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later for image gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using jquery fancybox and want to show gallery images 
but when I click on image it show me error "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later".

I want to add fancybox to my ajax content.. without ajax there is no problem.

I am using this code .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.fancybox', function() { 
        jQuery(".fancybox") .attr('rel', 'gal') .fancybox({ 
            prevEffect : 'none',     
            nextEffect : 'none', 
            helpers : { title : { type: 'outside' },
            thumbs : { width : 75, height : 75 } }, 
            padding : 0 
      }); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Not enough data provided. No one can help, i am afraid.

Comment: you should set image path in href="http://test.com/wp-contents/2016/12a.png"

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be like this

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1669/23976340262_a5ca3859f6_b.jpg" title="Twilight Memorie">
    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1669/23976340262_a5ca3859f6_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: Hello Vel, I want to add fancybox to my ajax content.. without ajax there  is no problem

Comment: I am using this code
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(document).on('click', '.fancybox', function() {      
jQuery(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gal')
.fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
                       },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 75,
                height  : 75
                        }
                    },

        padding : 0
    });
                    });
});

</script>

Comment: can you post your html part?

Comment: please delete the code from answer. I updated in question part